# Windows 8.1 pro, emergency-reset and browsers' history

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, opera, session-restore

Sometimes it happens, a program hangs up my computer, and I turn off the power, when I can't fix it somehow. I was extremely surprised!!! when (I have many tabs in my two browsers - opera 12 about 100 tabs, and 100 tabs in last ver. Firefox, I'm working and need all of them, to read and to check some details), after emergency-reloading the Windows clear my sessions in both of browsers and DELETE all history! I've used many versions of Windows, but this thing happens first time.

When it was happened, I tried to restore the previous state of system in 'windows restoring tool". The tool restored my data in Firefox, but opera lose all data forever. I was very sad, and I started to hope, that synchronization in browsers can save me. I registered in both of them and turned on the sync.

Today it happened again; the "windows system monitor" hanged. I have closed the Firefox accurately and started to pray, because I have to reset the computer.
The session is not opened, sync is not helped.

I do not satisfied the new windows behavior. How can I fix it? What should I do to keep my sessions, and never to think that tomorrow all will be broken?

Thank you in advance.